# render a circle onclick event in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, renderer

I have a requirement to render circles on click event in highcharts. The x,y value should be the point getting from click event I mean

```
var x = event.xAxis[0].value;
var y = event.yAxis[0].value;
```

If I click more than one point there should render another circle.

js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/WN3XC/1/

Comment: Yes it is possible to do using Highcharts.renderer(). what you want to get is not clear

Comment: Ok I created a fiddle ...but didn't get the point where i clicked...its adding circle outside the chart

http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/WN3XC/1/

Comment: renderer accepts the input positions in pixels, the click return axis units. you need to convert the axis units to pixels and then provide it to the renderer. API ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels

Comment: update your jsfiddle with working example over here http://jsfiddle.net/WN3XC/2/

Comment: Since it makes the answer, I've put the same in answers for further reference of others who visit this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poles,

Renderer draws the shape based on the inputs given to it. It accepts its input in pixels.

When you pass x and y positions for it to render they have to be in pixels, but the x and y values you will be getting from the click events will be in corresponding x and y units. You need to convert them into respective pixels and then pass them to the renderer.

For this highcharts has provided `toPixels()` method on both the axes. you can convert the axis Units into corresponding pixel positions using them

[API ref](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels)

I've updated your JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WN3XC/2/)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than a circle you can use the annotations plugin:
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations